# Привязка к одному компьютеру скрипта JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Есть скрипт на языке JavaScript, скрипт сделан под продажу, как сделать так, что бы скрипт работал только на том компьютере, на который его скачали/запустили?
Нашёл только модуль hwid в NPM
Если можно только им, подскажите как установить NPM в  VISUAL Code
Заранее благодарю!

Comment: В общем простом случае - никак, написать защиту будет намного сложней чем ее обойти.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков слишком запариваться там не надо, надо просто начальное, что бы скрипт не могли запускать на нескольких компьютерах

Comment: Любое ваше решение с которым не нужно заморачиваться до обфускации вскрывается как минимум в двое быстрей чем пишется, любое решение с обфускацией вскрывается как минимум в двое быстрей чем пишется с применением отладчика. единственная нормальная защита для JS - виртуальная машина с прекомпиляцией скриптов. т.е. если вы будете продавать свой скрипт по 100руб, я смогу продавать по 10(мне то нужно всего то защиту снять, а это пара минут делов). так понятней?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков это я понимаю, этот скрипт, если даже и вскроют, я ничего не потеряю, клиентская база этого скрипта не будет заниматься вскрытием защиты, это попросту того не стоит, но мне нужна лишь примитивная привязка к компьютеру, ибо в данный момент можно просто не открывая скопировать скрипт, и таким образом раздвоить его на несколько компьютеров, ах и да, извиняюсь за моё незнание  в вопросе программирования, я лишь только начинаю и занимаюсь тем, что дописываю чужой скрипт

Comment: Если вы дописываете **чужой** скрипт в любом виде - вам для начала стоит связаться с его автором и уточнить, не против ли он что вы собираетесь продавать его интеллектуальную собственность :) Если вы только учитесь(и реально учитесь), то первое направление я вам подсказал еще в прошлом комментарии, начните читать оттуда "обфускация", далее придумайте место где будете хранить идентификатор к которому привязался скрипт(при первом запуске) да так чтоб пользователь не нашел где эта настройка хранится. А уже после выбирайте к чему привязываться в плане железа(тут на самом деле просто очень).

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, не против, скрипт моего отца)
Что такое обфускация уже знаю
и она используется
Благодарю за помощь и диалог.
Всего вам хорошего!

Comment: По vs code https://imgur.com/a/l8WYAx0